# Using jQuery to create server side includes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to create server side includes, but I'd like to create a method to generate the content automatically based on the "title" attribute of the inserted  element, such as:

```
<div class="js-include" title="nav.html"></div>
<div class="js-include" title="table.html"></div>
```

That way one script could be used to generate multiple content elements.

The content files are stored in the same folder as the base file. Here is the script I am trying to use, but it's not working:

```
<script>
$(".js-include").each(function(){
    var inc=$(this);
    $.get(inc.attr("title"), function(data){
        inc.replaceWith(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: js must be at the end of html,if ajax is correct it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the code in `$(document).ready()` like so

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-include").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).attr("title"));
    });
});
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, make sure to check your browser's network/error console for HTTP errors.

Comment: One note, your "type" attribute is missing a closing quote (") mark. But otherwise it works like charm. I like neouser99's suggestion below to use a different attribute. But both suggestions worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably recommend you use data-* attributes instead of title="...". I would make more sense here I think. Also, you don't need to replaceWith or even get, jquery has an ajax overload to help you out.

```
<div class="js-include" data-page="nav.html"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".js-include").each(function () {
        $(this).load($(this).data('page'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not just it makes more sense to use `data-`, `title` also creates [unwanted tool tips](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.title) on the `div`s.

Comment: Very good idea. Your answer works fine. And I like the suggestion to use a different attribute.

Comment: OK, after trying this method on the actual site we have experience a major unintended consequence. The script definitely loads the external contents, but then it causes the browser to ignore all the rest of the webpage! You can find an example at this URL: http://amazingribs.com/includetest2.html
I disabled all other Scripts on the page to see if there were any conflicts but it still fails to load the rest of the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

hmm I think I understand what you wanna do. You wanna, using jQuery, load nav.html and put its content into that div?

Why don't you just do it from server side? If those divs are created server side, server knows during page load that they are needed there and can just include them, instead of leaving it for JS to handle.

I don't know how you could load nav.html using jQuery, maybe some AJAX/HTTP code. But once you have it on a variable, you can just use element.innerHTML to store any HTML text into a DOM element.

But, instead of having server setting a specific class and adding data into title attributes of some elements, (of course, not considering the better approach of server side just handling the include) I'd give these elements an id. Then, in the bottom of the HTML document, I'd print a JSON array holding those ids and what to do with them (in exemple the file to be loaded into them).

Then in a JS file I take that array, loop throu it and process its data as I want.

Edit: I never did such thing before, you gotta run it to test any sxyntax erros.

```
<?php
$fileslinks = array(
    array(
        'id'        => 'id1',
        'filename'  => 'file1.html'
    ),
    array(
        'id'        => 'id2',
        'filename'  => 'file2.html'
    ),
    array(
        'id'        => 'id3',
        'filename'  => 'file3.html'
    )
);
?>

<div id='id1'></div>
<div id='id2'></div>
<div id='id3'></div>

<script>
    var fileslinks = <?php echo json_encude($fileslinks); ?>;

    fileslinks.forEach(printFiles);

function printFiles(element, index, array){
    var fileContent = // load from element.filename
    document.getElementById(element.id).innerHTML = fileContent;
}


if(!Array.prototype.forEach){
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun){
        var len = this.length;
        if(typeof fun != "function")
            throw new TypeError();

        var thisp = arguments[1];
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if(i in this)
                fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show an example? The jQuery examples above work fine. But I don't know how to create the code you're describing. My goal was to create something that would not require changing the extension of the existing webpages to .asp, .php, or .shtml.

Comment: I still don't understand what you wanna do. What's the problem of changing the extention? Can't u use htaccess to redirect old file to new php?

Comment: My client doesn't want to change the extensions yet. We may be moving the whole site to PHP soon, but he only wants to do it once. If we do, we can use a simple PHP include statement. I was just trying to do this with jQuery to make it simple.

Comment: FYI, it wouldn't be 1 page. His site contains 100s of pages. So, any change would require redirecting all those pages too. If we can get the jQuery to work, we won't have to change anything else.